# Error while trying to canonize XML fragments in XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, libxml2, canonicalization, xml-libxml

I am trying to canonize a XML fragment to avoid printing of self closing nodes in the resultant XML. ( i want node `<test />` to be streamed as `<test></test>` due to constraints at the consuming system ).

I tried to use toStringC14N() method in the XML::LibXML::Node to achieve the same but I hit the following error on which I don't seems to get any help from google as well.

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $tagName  = 'testtag';
my $tagValue = '';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->createDocument->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $element = $doc->createElement($tagName);
$element->appendText($tagValue);
print "\nOut=>".$element->toStringC14N();
```

Output:

```
Failed to convert doc to string in doc->toStringC14N at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/XML/LibXML.pm line 1328.
```

I could only chase down the error till the following method in the LibXML.c

`xmlDocDumpMemory(self, &result, &len);`

I am clueless on what I am doing wrong as "toString()" seems to work fine.

I am using perl v5.8.8 & XML::LibXML version 1.88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the unit tests in XML::LibXML's test script t/24c14n.t get a $doc from $parser->parse_string and call toStringC14N on that.  Maybe there's something about createDocument that isn't round-trippable in respect to toStringC14N.  You could try asking on the XML::LibXML mailing list (see below).

Meanwhile, this does work:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->createDocument->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');

my $element = $doc->createElement($tagName);
$element->appendText($tagValue);
my $doc2 = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($element->toString);
print "\nOut=>".$doc2->toStringC14N()."\n";

#prints Out=><testtag></testtag>
```

> For suggestions etc., and other issues related to XML::LibXML you may
>   use the perl XML mailing list (perl-xml@listserv.ActiveState.com),
>   where most XML-related Perl modules are discussed. In case of problems
>   you should check the archives of that list first. Many problems are
>   already discussed there. You can find the list's archives and
>   subscription options at
>   http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Browse/Threaded/perl-xml.